# Error:(31, 0) SDK location not found. MAC OSX

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to clone this project
 [iTracing App](https://github.com/sylvek/itracing2) on my mac (Android Studio) but getting the error:

> Error:(31, 0) SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
>   Blockquote

I've tried all the solution regarding changing dir path to `sdk.dir = /Users/USER_NAME/Library/Android/sdk`
 after creating file named 
 `local.properties` 
 in root path of the project folder.

Comment: Locate the SDK directory
"sdk.dir=D\:\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk1"

Comment: I'm unable to reach to this path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put this in your .bash_profile (the file in your home directory /Users/USERNAME/.bash_profile)

```
export PATH="/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk"
```

and ANDROID_HOME environment variable will be accessible.

If it doesn't work - try to restart your system.